# simple input type file not getting the file

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-9

Hi im new to laravel 9 and im trying to upload file from view to controller, but somehow the input file didnt pass the file to controller.
im using laravel 9 with boostrap in it.

heres my code :

view

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('profile.put') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('POST')
    <div class="card-body">
        <input id="file" name="file" type="file">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">{{ __('Save') }}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

controller

```
public function put(Request $request){
    return $request;
}
```

i try to see the $request variable but the result is like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Th9Y.png)

i try the solution like add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` but still didnt work.

thank you in advance

Comment: have you read https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files and also no need to specify   @method('POST')

Comment: hi @JohnLobo thank you for answearing, im still reading now but im a bit confuse about it can you give me an example about it please.

Comment: can you show route also and controller

Comment: heres the router:
Route::post('profile/put', [\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'put'])->name('profile.put');

heres the controller
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Requests\ProfileUpdateRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function put(Request $request){
        return $request;
    }
}

Comment: if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        dd($request->file('file'));
    }

Comment: its working, i can get the file thank you, im sorry but can you explain it ?, cause in other tutorials they didnt use "$request->isMethod('POST')" but still work.

Comment: ah i get it i must use $request->file() to get the file instead the $request only ?

Comment: no need to use isMethod post unless if you are using same method for mulitple request types .you get file using only $request->file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I think you simply should get the request by its name or using `$request->all()`, you can do these two things:
```

In your controller you should write your put method like below:

```
 public function put(Request $request){
     $file = '';
     if($request->file('file'))
     {
       $file = $request->get('file);
     }
    
     return $file;
 }
```

or you can use the below code in your put method

```
public function put(Request $request){
     return $request->all();
 }
```

> Note: If you don't send the file as a `JSON Response` you should `return` it to `view` after saving operation;
> and also, there is no need to put `@method('POST')` inside the `form`;